# Batch Escaping Symbols In Echo

Tags: batch-file

So I'm trying to develop a quick batch program that will help me make items quickly in C# for a mod as its very time consuming to go through and change all the variables. But I'm having some problems doing things such as escaping > Symbols 
This is what i have so far, but ill need to be able to echo all the characters in [this document](https://github.com/blushiemagic/tModLoader/blob/master/ExampleMod/Items/Weapons/ExampleSword.cs)

```
(
echo using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
echo using Terraria;
echo using Terraria.ID;
echo using Terraria.ModLoader;
echo if (ceilingLimit > player.Center.Y - 200f)
) > var1.txt
```

Comment: You could use `^` as an escape character; but why don't you just write it in C# instead?

Comment: https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html

Comment: text processing with batch is not a good idea. PowerShell and bash are much better. And there are tons of duplicates on batch escaping

Answer (score 0):

Just realised that it was the fact that I wasn't escaping the brackets and other symbols as well, my bad.

Comment: In its current form, this is not an answer, merely a comment, please delete it or edit it in such a way as it more fully answers the question; thank you.